# How to submit Hive Jobs programmatically from JSP

Tags: rest, hadoop, hive

We are trying to build a wrapper system for business users and we want to explore option of building a capability to submit the HIVE query from a JSP page. I could not find a best example or suggested mechanism for this. Anyone tried this before? If so can someone share their best ideas? We are looking for the REST API mechanism. If that wont work, then we can use java from JSP servlets.

Appreciate your support.

Kiran

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDBC. I dont think there is a REST API for Hive.

But since most developers & application typically use JDBC this should be the preferred mode.

More details can be found here (Assuming you are using latest Hive versions) : [Hive 2 Clients](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients)

Sample code [sample code](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBCClientSampleCode)

Comment: Thank you Venkat. I will look into this API. Meanwhile, please share if you have any sample code.